# How do you parse this json(with $)?

Tags: c#, json, google-api, restsharp

I setup my google api results to return Json instead of xml but I am kinda confused when I saw this

```
   "openSearch$totalResults":{
         "$t":"3"
      },
```

I don't get what the `$t:3` is for and how to actually store this information in a property. I am using restsharp and I can't just do

```
   public string $t3 { get; set; }
```

as that is illegal character. If I just do `openSearch$totalResults` again because of the "$" sign. Plus I think if I even could do it it would store "$t:3" and I would have to parse it what would be kinda lame.

Comment: I don't think suing someone because you cant figure out how to use data from another company is the right way to go.. but that's just me.    ;-)

Comment: I can suggest you to use JSON.NET i know he can desirialize this JSON